# Setting global variables in working memory in Drools planner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

How do I add a global variable to working memory in drools planner's solver to be able to use in scores drool. This is similar to https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2700 but couldn't find a solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be looking for is a `@ProblemFactProperty`.
Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#problemFacts):

> All objects returned by those [annotated] methods will be inserted into the
>   ConstraintStreams or Drools session, so the constraint steams or score
>   rules can access them.

In my own words: You can hold a reference to your global object in your `@PlanningSolution` class. If you annotate its `getter` with `@ProblemFactProperty` you can access it from your drools file.

Comment: I agree with this new answer. Ignore my very old answer.

Answer (score 1):

First some preaching: Using a service (set as a global) to calculate part of the score will break **delta based score calculation** (read the manual section on that topic), resulting in much less score calculations per second (say 50 instead of 5000 per second on big data sets).

Then a HACK solution: In the StartingSolutionInitializer (soon known as CustomSolverPhaseCommand) do `solverScope.getWorkingMemory().setGlobal("key", value)`.

Then a real, long-term solution: Could you motivate why you need to be able to do this? We can think about adding support for this with something like an optional `WorkingMemoryPreperator`.

Comment: I actually have constant/s which should be kept in Rule file ( although I know that for such things we can create static fields in some class ). This constant/s would be useful for some of the conditions in the rule  (when section). This is easily achievable in normal drools ( ksession.setGlobal ) but not possible through drools planner.

Comment: Then the delta calculation preaching doesn't apply :) This sounds like a valid use cases, please add it to the jira issue.

Comment: @comeonman Can you take a look at InstitionalWeightings in the Examination example? Those are also these kind of constants, and they are just considered part of the problem facts (and set correctly before calling the solve() method).

Answer (score 1):

After set the planningProblem:

```
solver.setPlanningProblem(planningProblem);
```

You can get access the workingMemory via solutionDirector(HACK) :

```
DefaultSolutionDirector solutionDirector = ((DefaultSolver)solver).getSolverScope().getSolutionDirector();
solutionDirector.getWorkingMemory().setGlobal("list", new ArrayList<String>());
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use some helper methods in the planner rules, try the following approach which I used in my project:

1. Create a utility class which includes the helper methods.
2. Import the utility class in the rule file like importing it in a java class.
3. Use the helper method in the rule. If you want to use a helper method in the condition, wrap using eval(). If you want to use a helper method in the then part, just use it as normal java method call.

For example, say you have a utility class named PlanningUtil like below:

```
public class PlanningUtil {
  public boolean isGood() {return true;}

  public void doSomething() {//...}
}
```

Then import the utility class in the rule file,

```
import PlanningUtil;
```

Use the utility method in the rule

```
rule "MyRule"
  when
    eval(PlanningUtil.isGood())
  then
    PlanningUtil.doSomething(); // note the ';' is a must. 
end
```