# global variable in optaplanner

Tags: global-variables, drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

In drools rule file how do I set the value of (or initialize) a global variable for optaplanner. My use case is following:

I want to declare a global java map that is constant and will not change during the execution. Every rule will access the map to check for a value, if value is in the map then rule will evaluate to false. The map is being generated before execution starts by accessing data in files/database.

This link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-94 is also requesting the access to global variable but this feature is rejected now.

How do i use the hack defined in this link: [Setting global variables in working memory in Drools planner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855209/setting-global-variables-in-working-memory-in-drools-planner), from which object i should get CustomSolverPhaseCommand? [I am not able to comment on this post yet because i don't have enough reputation, sorry if it seems duplicate question].

I am creating SolverFactory from xml Resource and xml file contains the path to .drl file. Just like in .drl we can access object HardSoftScoreHolder scoreHolder, I want to access the map in the same way in 'then' part of rule.

can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the examples that have a class that ends with **`Parameterization`** instead, such as `ConferenceParametrization`, this is probably a better alternative than globals.

Comment: I looked at the **Parametrization** class and I think 
the reference ConferenceParametrization is slightly different than what I am looking for. Because In my case I have java map as part of planning entity that represents some historical data that i need to use during planning. Though to get things going I have modeled my problem in a similar fashion but I am not sure if calling **paratmerization** class from drools file is a good design.

Comment: Can you please opine on this:
I put some hard coded data in **parametrization** class and also added a public function that i call from drools file.
In drools file i had to access the parameter class as below: 
<code>
$param: MyParametrization()
  eval(!$param.isPriorUse($type, $month)) 
</code>

I don't see any such sample code. Though this works and solved my problem. Thank you for helping!!